# Encrypt string using One Time Pad

Tags: java, random, cryptography

I'm trying to make it so that a string generates n keys, and all of those are required to recover the original string. For this, I generate n-1 random strings, XOR them all together with the original string to get the nth one. XORing these n strings reproduces the original strings

How secure is this? Is there any better method?

Also, is the code itself good enough? What can I do to improve it in terms of security/speed/readability/best practices?

```
package crypto;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

/**
 * Created by hooda on 2/3/2015.
 */
public class XOR {

    //Testing the functionality.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XOR xor = new XOR();

        String text = "Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four Privet Drive, were proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much.";
        String[] pieces = xor.encrypt(text, 5);
        System.out.println(pieces[0]);
        System.out.println(pieces[1]);
        System.out.println(pieces[2]);
        System.out.println(pieces[3]);
        System.out.println(pieces[4]);
        String test = xor.decrypt(pieces);
        System.out.println(test);

    }

    public String[] encrypt(String s, int n) throws Exception {
        int length = s.length();
        String[] pieces = new String[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            pieces[i] = keyGen(length);
        }

        String nth = s;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            nth = doXOR(pieces[i], nth);
        }

        pieces[n - 1] = nth;
        return pieces;
    }

    public String decrypt(String[] pieces) {

        String decrypted = new String(new char[pieces[0].length()]).replace("\0", Character.toString((char) 0));
        for (String piece : pieces) {
            decrypted = doXOR(piece, decrypted);
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

    public String toBinary(String s) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("ASCII");
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            int val = b;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                val <<= 1;
            }
        }
        return binary.toString();
    }


    public String keyGen(int length) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        SecureRandom srand = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        srand.nextBytes(bytes);
        return new String(bytes, "ASCII");
    }

    public String doXOR(String s1, String s2) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        String ret;
        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The bit strings must have equal length!");
        } else {
            ret = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
                char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
                char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
                int i1 = (int) c1;
                int i2 = (int) c2;
                int i3 = i1 ^ i2;
                char c3 = (char) i3;
                ret += c3;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Security**. `xor` is an associative operation.

  ```
      nth ^= pieces[0];
      nth ^= pieces[1];
      ...
      nth ^= pieces[n-2]
  ```

  like your code does is as good as

  ```
      nth ^= (pieces[0] ^ pieces[1] ^ ... ^ pieces[n-2]
  ```
- `doXOR` is way too verbose to my taste.
- `toBinary` doesn't belong here (and is never called indeed, unless I am missing something).
  Obviously all the keys you have generated collapse into a single one. The bad guy doesn't have to recover all the keys - he only needs their accumulated `xor`. There is no additional security.

Comment: Yes, it is obvious now. I may as well be using only one key. Can you suggest an alternative way?

Answer (score 1):

The one time pad is not really a secure encryption algorithm.

It leaks information, since it does not provide **perfect secrecy** (*The cypher text should not reveal any information about the plain text*). Even if it only leads to assumptions, one can still perform statistical analysis to discover the real meaning.

---

**Example:**

You have 2 messages (m1,m2) , which you will encrypt with a key k

```
Enc(m1,k)=m1⊕k
Enc(m2,k)=m2⊕k
```

If an attacker manages to intercept both encrypted messages, he can perform a xor on it and end up with the xor-ed plain texts.

```
(m1⊕k)⊕(m2⊕k)=m1⊕m2
```

But there is an even more important problem!
Due to the re-use of the key for each message, if an attacker manages to guess/knows one of your plaintext messages, they can find your key:

```
(m1⊕k)⊕m1=k
```

This results in them being able to read every single encrypted message you sent (encrypted by that key).

---

Also the 2 time pad and many time pad are considered unsafe.
In case you need a more secure encryption algorithm, may I suggest to look into AES and RSA.

Comment: Yes, but that depends on me using the same key for two messages. This is not the case.